# What is the refresh rate of the random() method in C#

Tags: c#, random, refresh

I am going to generate 100 random numbers in a for loop. The only problem is that since the random() method is timer-based, it will generate the same numbers 3-4 times in a row.
I can solve this problem by including a threat.sleep() method in my loop. Therefor i want to know the exact refresh rate of the random() method so that i can match the threat.sleep() method and not get delayed more than necessary.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i; i <= 100; i += 1)
{        
    Random rndNum = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(rndNum.Next(1, 100));
    Thread.Sleep(X); //I want to know the best value of X (as less delay as possible) 
}
```

Thanks a bunch

/HamMan4Ever

Comment: Don't generate a `new Random()` each iteration. Generate a `new Random()` *before* the loop, and reuse it throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is equal to the refresh rate of the system clock as it uses the time as a seed. But for your job, you should keep the Random instance outside the loop.

```
Random rndNum = new Random();
for (int i; i <= 100; i += 1)
{        
    Console.WriteLine(rndNum.Next(1, 100));
}
```

Since it uses the time as a seed, it uses it only ones and will generate random numbers even if you call it multiple times at the same time as long as you use the same instance.

Comment: Saying that the refresh rate matches the system clock is misleading and feeds OP's incorrect notion that there is such a thing as a refresh rate when invoking the methods on the `Random` class.  There is not.

Comment: While there is no refresh rate, because it uses the system time, the refresh rate will match the rate at which the time is updated.

Comment: I'm not sure we have the same definition of *refresh rate*.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard or read that the `Random` class is timer-based.  You may have heard that it is *seeded* by the system time, but after that each call to `Next` will return a randomish number typically different from the previous.  Typically when you see non-random data coming from a `Random`, it's because you're creating a new random on each iteration through a loop, as you are in the code you shared.  Since each is seeded from the system clock and you're creating several very quickly, you see repeated patterns.  Create your `Random` outside the loop to make this problem go away.